# Operation with Sigma

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

How demonstrate that operation: $$1)\sum _{k=1}^{2n}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}}{k}\:+2\sum _{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{2k}\right)\:=\:\sum _{k=1}^{2n}\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)$$

$$2)\sum _{k=1}^{2n}\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)-\sum _{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)=\sum _{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{k+n}\right)$$

Comment: Try decomposing the sum into even and odd portions.

Comment: The second equality is wrong, I think - the right side should be $\sum_{k=1}^n$, not $\sum_{k=1}^{2n}$

Comment: And absolutely none of those parentheses are necessary. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that you are trying to verify these equalities… Let's consider the second equality, so as not to ruin the fun of trying this on your own:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k+n}$$
You may notice that there is some similarity on the left hand side. If not, it is sometimes helpful to let $n$ equal some relatively small natural number, say $n=4$, and evaluate the expression. For sake of brevity, lets try to split up the bigger summand and see what might cancel:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}+\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}$$
So, you now have:
\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}+\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}=\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}\end{align}
And you can rewrite the RHS so that $k\in\{1,… , 2n\}$.

(If this is not immediate, try to sum up the first few terms and I think you will see it.)

Comment: hey erik, there exists for formula?

Comment: Exists for formula? I am not sure I understand your question.. Are you asking if there is a formula to apply which splits the summands?

Comment: formula in general case

Comment: You can, when dealing with finite sums, split the summands up as desired. In this case we have a clear direction and getting there is just a matter of simplifying. Hence, the goal in this splitting is simply to combine, or eliminate, terms from the LHS.
The splitting of sums in the infinite case is not so easy. (Splitting sums in different ways will yield different results). There are some nice examples of this in most introductory analysis (even calculus) courses.